# different color for each menu item once you are in that page

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, styles, menuitem

```
<li id="menu-item-1769" class="Par menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-1769"><a href="http://wp.thecmr.com/parents/">Parents</a></li>
```

So, I have that code in WordPress and it is an option in my menu. What I want to do to make the color different once I am in my "Parent" page.

For example, when I click on the menu "parent" I will go to parents page but I want the "parent Button" have a red color till I leave the Parents page.

[image]

Any suggestion with the CSS?

Comment: Can you show more code or a graph of what you want?

Comment: I added the picture. So I want the Parents in the menu have red color once i am in the parents page am I clear? I want different color for each menu item and page

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are asking two things here.

1. You want the active menu item to display in a certain color.
2. You want the color to be unique to each menu item.

Let's tackle each task individually, it may help you understand what is required better.

1. In order to make the active menu item a different color than the standard black, we must apply styles to it's active class.
   This may be different depending on the theme you are using, if you inspect the element of the current and compare it to the other link elements you will be able to find out the class name you are looking to target.
   In my example the theme uses a class called `current-menu-item`.

   Let's create a style for this class

   ```
       // css
       .current-menu-item {
         color: red;
       }
   ```

Now you can see how we have styled the active class, the next step we will make a unique color for each menu item.

2. This is quite a simple process, it can be done in many ways, you can add a class in the Wordpress menu or you can use the automated id selectors to target the menu item. In this example I can see that you have the automated id selector of `#menu-item-1769`, so let's use that.

   ```
   // css
   #menu-item-1769 .current-menu-item {
       color: red;
   }
   ```

   To help illustrate the point I will assume you have a few more menu items, let's apply colors to them.

   ```
   // css
   #menu-item-1769.current-menu-item {
       color: red;
   }
   #menu-item-1770.current-menu-item {
       color: pink;
   }
   #menu-item-1771.current-menu-item {
       color: green;
   }

   // Depending on the theme you may have to target a child selector
   // In this case the following may be suitable
   #menu-item-1769.current-menu-item a {
       color: red;
   }
   ```

This should be enough to get you started, if you need any more help, let me know.

Have a nice day

Comment: thank you for your time!!

Here is the thing :
when I am in home page I want all the menu Item to be black but as I change the page such as parent or baby and etc.. I want that specific menu Item have different color. For example when I am in Baby page I want it to have red font in menu and the rest of menu item have back font and I tried your code it did not work

Comment: That is how i interpreted your issue, so we are on the same wavelength, i'll try offer some more help...

1. Have you identified the active class that your Wordpress theme uses? (`current-menu-item`)

2. Have you correctly named the menu item id's? (`#menu-item-1771`)

3. You must place the new styles after any previous styling that the theme applies, this is how CSS works, the last rule in the file will be used, all previous rules are ignored, (except !important rules).

4. Is the .css file loading, server or browser cache could be loading an older version.

Let me know how you go

Comment: Another thing to try is targeting the a tag, as it may very likely be applying a color and overriding your new styles. The following adjustment to the code should ensure a result, Obviously replace the menu id and active class with your own.

#menu-item-1771.current-menu-item a{
    color: green!important;
}

Comment: #menu-item-1771.current-menu-item a{ color: green!important; }  saved my life it worked thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should also be able to get page-id from each of your page.

So go ahead and write in your css file:

```
#page-id-1234 #menu-item-1769 {background-color: red;}
#page-id-1235 #menu-item-1770 {background-color: blue;}
#page-id-1236 #menu-item-1771 {background-color: yellow;}
```

Comment: body.page-id-12426 #menu-item-1769 {background-color: red!important;} try this

Comment: This solution works if you have a unique class name for each pages.  If it says <body class="category category-31 right-sidebar"> ..... <nav> <ul> <li id="menu-item-1769"> body.category-31 #menu-item-1769 {background-color:red;} will do.